# Can i add method after method being executed meld aop

Tags: javascript, function, aop, method-modifier, cujojs

Consider I have class

```
 function home {}{
   this.door=function(){},
   this.tiles=function(){}
 }
```

I have to add some message after it's methods are called using this library called meld js (https://github.com/cujojs/meld/blob/master/docs/api.md#meldafter)

my try

```
var allMethods = new home();

   Object.keys(allMethods).forEach(function(k){

       aop.after(Object.prototype,key,function(){
            console.log('Dont use me i am old')
       });
  })
```

is this a right approach  ?

Comment: Regarding the `AOP` tag, wrapping and reassigning already declared functionality (be it functions or methods) misses any aspect of _AOP_. Any language which wants to qualify for the latter has to provide abstraction levels for at least `Joinpoint`, `Advice` and `Aspect`. The use case described by the OP should be referred to as method modification, and JavaScript of cause is well suited for this scenario and could easily provide a complete `target`/`context` aware toolset of method modifiers like `around`, `before`, `after`, `afterThrowing` and `afterFinally` via `Function.prototype`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct but you have several errors in your code.
First, the `home` function should have `()` instead of `{}`:

```
function home() {
    this.door=function(){},
    this.tiles=function(){}
}
```

Second, in your `AOP` code you need to provide the object to the `after()` method and not the prototype.

```
var allMethods = new home();
Object.keys(allMethods).forEach(function(k){
    aop.after(allMethods,k,function(){
        console.log('Dont use me i am old')
    });
})
```

(Also you need to use variable `k` and not `key` since that's the one defined in the `forEach` method)

If you'll run one of the methods you'll get the wished output.

```
allMethods.door() // result 'Dont use me i am old'
```

Comment: sure. if you don't mind I appreciate selecting my answer as the chosen one.

Comment: upvote question so people will find it usefull later.